# AWS Lambda SNS/SQS not notifying me of increase in resources(Error message given)

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

*ERROR MESSAGE AT BOTTOM OF POST*

I've setup a serverless architecture where my Cloudformation stack deploys a S3 bucket, customer and order table with content within once my text file with the content in is uploaded to the S3 bucket. The content displays fine once uploaded to my S3 bucket within DynamoDB 'Items' but I am receiving no SNS to my email inputted.

The error message is linked below in relation to  `for record in event['Records']:`

Here is the code for my lambda function.

```
# TotalNotifier Lambda function
#
from __future__ import print_function
import json, boto3

# Connect to SNS
sns = boto3.client('sns')
alertTopic = 'HighOrderPurchaseAlertSNSTopic'
snsTopicArn = [t['TopicArn'] for t in sns.list_topics()['Topics'] if t['TopicArn'].lower().endswith(':' + alertTopic.lower())][0]
print(snsTopicArn)

# Connect to DynamoDB
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
orderTotalTableName = 'OrderTotal'
orderTotalTable = dynamodb.Table(orderTotalTableName);

# This handler is executed every time the Lambda function is triggered
def lambda_handler(event, context):

  # Show the incoming event in the debug log
  print("Event received by Lambda function: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

  # For each order added, calculate the new order Total
  for record in event['Records']:
    customerId = record['dynamodb']['NewImage']['CustomerId']['S']
    orderAmount = int(record['dynamodb']['NewImage']['OrderAmount']['N'])

    # Update the customer's total in the OrderTotal DynamoDB table
    response = orderTotalTable.update_item(
      Key={
        'CustomerId': customerId
      },
      UpdateExpression="add accountOrder :val",
      ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':val': orderAmount
      },
      ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )

    # Retrieve the latest order purchase
    latestAccountBalance = response['Attributes']['accountOrder']
    print("Latest account balance: " + format(latestAccountOrder))

    # If order > 10, send a message to SNS
    if latestAccountBalance >= 10:

      # Construct message to be sent
      message = '{"customerID": "' + customerId + '", ' + '"accountOrder": "' + str(latestAccountOrder) + '"}'
      print(message)

      # Send message to SNS
      sns.publish(
        TopicArn=snsTopicArn,
        Message=message,
        Subject='Warning! High Account Order',
        MessageStructure='raw'
      )

  # Finished!
  return 'Successfully processed {} records.'.format(len(event['Records']))
```

[Content within DynamoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHLAk.png)

CloudFormation Stack code:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description" : "Implementing a Serverless Architecture with AWS Managed Services",
  "Resources": {
    "InputS3BucketForCustOrdersFiles": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    },
    "CustomerDynamoDBTable": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties": {
        "TableName": "Customer",
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "CustomerId",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "CustomerId",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "ReadCapacityUnits": "5",
          "WriteCapacityUnits": "5"
        }
      }
    },
    "OrdersDynamoDBTable": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "DependsOn": "CustomerDynamoDBTable",
      "Properties": {
        "TableName": "Orders",
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "CustomerId",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "OrderId",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "OrderId",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "CustomerId",
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "ReadCapacityUnits": "5",
          "WriteCapacityUnits": "5"
        }
      }
     },
    "OrdersIAMRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": "OrdersIAMRole",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
              },
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess",
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess"
        ],
        "Policies": [ {
           "PolicyName": "CWLogsPolicy",
           "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version" : "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                  {
                    "Action": [
                      "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                      "logs:CreateLogStream",
                      "logs:PutLogEvents"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
                    "Effect": "Allow"
                  }
              ]}
           }
         ]
      }
    },
    "TotalNotifierRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": "TotalNotifierRole",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Sid": "",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
              },
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSNSFullAccess",
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess"
        ],
        "Policies": [
          {
           "PolicyName": "CWLogsPolicy",
           "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version" : "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                  {
                    "Action": [
                      "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                      "logs:CreateLogStream",
                      "logs:PutLogEvents"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
                    "Effect": "Allow"
                  }
              ]}
           },
           {
            "PolicyName": "CWLogPolicy",
            "PolicyDocument": {
               "Version" : "2012-10-17",
               "Statement": [
                   {
                     "Action": [
                      "dynamodb:GetRecords",
                      "dynamodb:GetShardIterator",
                      "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                      "dynamodb:ListStreams"
                     ],
                     "Resource": "*",
                     "Effect": "Allow"
                   }
               ]}
            }
         ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "InputS3BucketForCustOrdersFiles": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "InputS3BucketForCustOrdersFiles"
      },
      "Description": "Name of the S3 bucket in which orders from customers should be uploaded"
    },
    "CustomerDynamoDBTable": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "CustomerDynamoDBTable"
      },
      "Description": "Customer table in DynamoDB"
    },
    "OrdersDynamoDBTable": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "OrdersDynamoDBTable"
      },
      "Description": "Orders in DynamoDB."
    },
  }
}
```

[image: error n2]

[image]

[dyanmo test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUxdB.png)

[Stream is closed DynamoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJObO.png)

Comment: Has the email subscription on the Amazon SNS Topic been confirmed? If you send a message to the SNS Topic via the management console, is it received? If so, this suggests that the code is not reaching the `publish()` command. Does your `print(message)` output appear correctly in the logs? If you use `response = sns.publish(...)`, what is the contents of the `response`?

Comment: When I pushed a message within my SNS Topic with random chars it sent to my specified email. Will try what u mentioned now

Comment: I uploaded the response I received in the post

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Any idea what the error could be? Not sure looking at that myself, it's not very specific

Comment: Actually I noticed, I misnamed my Topic which seemed to be the issue but now running into another issue in the updated post. I'm not sure what 'event' relates to in "for record in event['Records']"

Comment: Are you wanting the Lambda function to run after information is entered into DynamoDB? Has the Lambda function been configured with the DynamoDB table as a Trigger?

Comment: Looks like you have asked an updated, but very similar, question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70050187/aws-lambda-sns-sqs-not-notifying-me-of-increase-in-resourceserror-message-given). If this question (70050187) has been resolved please either accept the provided answer, if it helped, or close whichever question no longer needs to be answered.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are running this function via the **Test** button in the AWS Lambda console. When doing so, you can specify the contents of the `event` that will be sent to the function.

The log files are showing that your Test passed this event to the function:

```json
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

This is a 'fake' event and it clearly does not contain anything about a DynamoDB stream. Instead, you should **create a test event by choosing the DynamoDB example template** and configuring appropriate values in the test.

Or, trigger the event by updating information in DynamoDB, with a stream configured as a trigger to the AWS Lambda function.

Comment: Is what I put in the post what you are referring to with creating a test event using dynamoDB? although it only shows 2 options for a dynamoDB template. I attempted with dynamodb-update.

Comment: It also says "Stream is closed" in the screenshot when inspecting my trigger, how could I enable this?